# How to remove chart axis and lines using C# with interop library?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, interop, office-interop, powerpoint-interop

I have a chart with some data present in it. I don't want to show the x and Y axis. I somehow find out how to remove the legend in the chart. But failed to hide the axis.

[image]

I just want to remove the Grid line and Axes also. I have the chart object with the below code.

```
  PowerPoint.Shape chartShape = slide.Shapes.AddChart(Microsoft.Office.Core.XlChartType.xlBarClustered, left, top, width, height);

  //Get the chart
  PowerPoint.Chart chart = chartShape.Chart;
  chart.Legend.Clear();
```

Can anyone knows how to hide it with c#?

Comment: Create a similar chart in Excel, then use Excel's VBA macro recorder to record what happens when you make the changes you want manually. That'll often give you a good idea of how to use the chart object model programmatically.

Comment: I use c# for my addon. Is this help for me.

Comment: I record the detail it shows `ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisNone)` but I can't find a way to use this in c# VSTO addon.

Comment: I don't use C#, so can't really help with translating from VBA, but I'd imagine you'd start with chart.SetElement ... etc

Comment: Thanks. Very useful comment. Can you post it as an answer? The SetElement thing was working well.

Comment: Glad it helped; but rather than (C# VSTO clueless) me posting an answer, please post the answer yourself along with a simple code sample showing how you solved the problem. That'd be much more useful and trustworthy to future visitors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance...will update this with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Aspose.Slides for .NET](https://products.aspose.com/slides/net/) instead of Office Interop, you will hide the chart legend, axes and gridlines as shown below:

```cs
    using var presentation = new Presentation();
    var chart = presentation.Slides[0].Shapes.AddChart(ChartType.ClusteredBar, 20, 20, 400, 300);
    
    chart.HasLegend = false;
    
    chart.Axes.VerticalAxis.IsVisible = false;
    chart.Axes.HorizontalAxis.IsVisible = false;
    
    chart.Axes.HorizontalAxis.MajorGridLinesFormat.Line.FillFormat.FillType = FillType.NoFill;
    
    // Save the chart with default data
    presentation.Save("result.pptx", SaveFormat.Pptx);
```

Result with default data:

[image]

[Documentation](https://docs.aspose.com/slides/net/) | [API Reference](https://apireference.aspose.com/slides) | [Free forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/slides/)

You can also evaluate [Aspose.Slides Cloud](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/) for presentation manipulating. This REST-based API allows you to make 150 free API calls per month for API learning and presentation processing.

I work at Aspose.